# Why this column alignment for multiple locations fail?

Tags: matrices, alignment

Two distinct blocks (`eq.1` & `eq.2`) in the following document are almost identical except; a single line (representing the dimensions of the matrices) are added in `eq.2` (marked with the *blue* box).

However, when I tried to align the matrix dimensions with corresponding matrices,

1. an extra space is added after the `\cdot` & `=`,
2. also, the alignment for the sigma `\sum` is lost.

Can someone elaborate what am I doing wrong?

[image: The pdf output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix*}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n}\\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & ... & a_{2n}\\
        ...\\
        a_{p1} & a_{p2} & ... & a_{pn}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \cdot
    \begin{bmatrix*}
        b_{11} & b_{12} & ... & b_{1q}\\
        b_{21} & b_{22} & ... & b_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        b_{n1} & b_{n2} & ... & b_{nq}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix*}
        c_{11} & c_{12} & ... & c_{1q}\\
        c_{21} & c_{22} & ... & c_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        c_{p1} & c_{p2} & ... & c_{pq}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \hfill c_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_{ik} \cdot b_{kj} \qquad
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\\ \\ \\
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &A\ (p \times n) &&B\ (n \times q) & &C\ (p \times q)\\
    &\begin{bmatrix*}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n}\\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & ... & a_{2n}\\
        ...\\
        a_{p1} & a_{p2} & ... & a_{pn}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \cdot
    &&\begin{bmatrix*}
        b_{11} & b_{12} & ... & b_{1q}\\
        b_{21} & b_{22} & ... & b_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        b_{n1} & b_{n2} & ... & b_{nq}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    =
    & &\begin{bmatrix*}
        c_{11} & c_{12} & ... & c_{1q}\\
        c_{21} & c_{22} & ... & c_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        c_{p1} & c_{p2} & ... & c_{pq}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \hfill c_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_{ik} \cdot b_{kj} \qquad
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related: With modern versions of LaTeX, you do not nee `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row]
        \Block{1-4}{A(p\times n)} \\
        a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n}\\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & ... & a_{2n}\\
        ...\\
        a_{p1} & a_{p2} & ... & a_{pn}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row]
        \Block{1-4}{B(n\times p)} \\
        b_{11} & b_{12} & ... & b_{1q}\\
        b_{21} & b_{22} & ... & b_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        b_{n1} & b_{n2} & ... & b_{nq}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
    =
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row]
        \Block{1-4}{C(p\times q)} \\
        c_{11} & c_{12} & ... & c_{1q}\\
        c_{21} & c_{22} & ... & c_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        c_{p1} & c_{p2} & ... & c_{pq}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
    \hfill c_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_{ik} \cdot b_{kj} \qquad
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'll wait a little while for a better solution may show up. If not, I'll mark yours as an answer. BTW, when I change the line `\Block{1-4}{A\ (p\times n)}` into `\Block{1-2}{A\ (p\times n)}` (replaced 4 with 2), the dimensions are now aligned to the left of the matrices. Is it a tweak or an acceptable solution? Is there a more concise way to align them to the left?

Comment: To align to the left, the best way is to write `\Block[l]{1-4}{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

I displaced the ampersands, used `alignedat` and added some manual spacing in the first row.

Unrelated, `nccmath` should be loaded *before* `mathtools. Also, no need to load` amsmath as both nccmath and mathtools load it. And no need to load inputenc if your  distribution is not too old (utf8 is now the default).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix*}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n}\\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & ... & a_{2n}\\
        ...\\
        a_{p1} & a_{p2} & ... & a_{pn}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \cdot
    \begin{bmatrix*}
        b_{11} & b_{12} & ... & b_{1q}\\
        b_{21} & b_{22} & ... & b_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        b_{n1} & b_{n2} & ... & b_{nq}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix*}
        c_{11} & c_{12} & ... & c_{1q}\\
        c_{21} & c_{22} & ... & c_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        c_{p1} & c_{p2} & ... & c_{pq}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \hfill c_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_{ik} \cdot b_{kj} \qquad
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\\ \\ \\
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}[b]{3}
    &\enspace A\ (p \times n) &&\quad\mathrlap{B\ (n \times q)} & &\hspace{1.6em} C\ (p \times q) \\
    &\begin{bmatrix*}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n}\\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & ... & a_{2n}\\
        ...\\
        a_{p1} & a_{p2} & ... & a_{pn}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    &&\cdot\begin{bmatrix*}
        b_{11} & b_{12} & ... & b_{1q}\\
        b_{21} & b_{22} & ... & b_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        b_{n1} & b_{n2} & ... & b_{nq}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    & & =
\begin{bmatrix*}
        c_{11} & c_{12} & ... & c_{1q}\\
        c_{21} & c_{22} & ... & c_{2q}\\
        ...\\
        c_{p1} & c_{p2} & ... & c_{pq}
    \end{bmatrix*}
    \enspace\; c_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_{ik} \cdot b_{kj}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]